# Garbage collector: перемещение объекта из поколения в поколение

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Когда у нас заполняется нулевое поколение кучи, происходит анализ этого поколения: удаляются "мёртвые"  объекты и *перемещаются* "выжившие" в следующее поколение - 1. 
 Вопрос: если в поколении 1 недостаточно места для приёма объектов из нулевой кучи, то что происходит? Очистка первого поколения?

---

## UPDATE

Цитата (C# 5.0 in Nutshell, Albahari):

> Среда CLR сохраняет раздел Gen() относительно небольшим (максимум 16 Мбайт в 32-битной версии для рабочей станции, с типичным размером от нескольких сотен Кбайт до нескольких Мбайт). Когда раздел Gen() заполняется, сборщик мусора GC инициирует сборку Gen() — что происходит относительно часто. Сборщик мусора применяет похожий порог памяти к разделу Gen1 (который действует как буфер для Gen2), поэтому сборки Gen1 являются тоже относительно быстрыми и частыми. Однако полные сборки мусора, включающие Gen2, занимают намного больше времени и, таким образом, происходят нечасто. Результат полной сборки мусора показан на рис. 12.2.

Comment: А почему вдруг там место ограничено?

Comment: @VladD читал, мол каждое поколение ограничено в размере... Или это неправда?

Comment: @VladD а как тогда происходит очистка в моем случае?

Comment: Хм, а откуда информация, что каждое поколение ограничено в размере? Я думал, что ограничение происходит на уровне суммарного размера.

Comment: @VladD в пост добавил информацию

Comment: @VladD "...порог памяти к разделу Gen1"... Отсюда и встал вопрос: если в поколении 1 доступно, например 1-2Кб памяти, следовательно ПОКОЛЕНИЕ не готово к очистке, а нулевое требует очистки, и готовые к перемещению объекты из 0 в 1 занимают 10Кб памяти, то как тут работает GC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достижение поколением порогового размера — всего лишь триггер для начала сборки мусора. Когда общий размер объектов в Gen0 станет больше порога, запустится сборщик мусора.

Когда сборщик мусора запустится, он смотрит, не превышает ли суммарный размер объектов в Gen2 порог. Если да, запускается полная, медленная сборка мусора всех трёх поколений.

Если Gen2 в порядке, но суммарный размер объектов а Gen1 превышает порог для Gen1, запускается ускоренная сборка, которая рассматривает **только** Gen0 и Gen1.

Если же Gen1 тоже в порядке, то запускается ускоренная сборка только Gen0.

Если после сборки Gen0 переполнится Gen1 (то есть, суммарный размер Gen1 станет выше порога), ничего не произойдёт до следующего запуска сборщика мусора. А когда он таки запустится (по переполнению Gen0), он обнаружит переполнение поколения Gen1 и соберёт его тоже.

(Кстати, размеры порогов на текущий момент не фиксированы, и фреймворк динамически подгоняет их во время пробега программы.)

---

Литература: [Jeffrey Richter. *The Managed Heap and Garbage Collection in the CLR*](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224054&seqNum=2).

Comment: ага... Просто я понимал порог как "жесткая граница", которую нельзя превысить...

Comment: а все-таки... У поколения есть какие-то "жесткие границы", дальше которых невозможно добавить объекты? (Вопрос про 1 поколение). Про второе читал, мол, дополнительные сегменты могут выделяться

Comment: @khirnick: Границ нету, просто если их становится слишком много, происходит сборка. Ну и вы не можете руками добавить туда объект, его добавляет сборщик мусора сам.

Comment: при очистке 2-ого поколения, автоматически очищаются и 1, и 0 поколение? (При сборке мусора в старших поколениях в обязательном порядке убирается мусор и во всех младших.) - https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/GC.xml

Comment: просто в некоторых местах пишут различную информацию, и я иногда путаюсь: где же истина)

Comment: @khirnick: «Переполнение» второго поколения вызывает «полную» сборку, в которой участвуют все поколения. Так что да.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: @khirnick: Уточнил ответ на основе статьи Рихтера

Comment: а такой вопрос: если превышен порог 1-ого поколения, то сначала запускается сборка 1-ого или 0-го?

Comment: @khirnick: Если превышен порог первого поколения, ничего не происходит. Триггером является превышение порога нулевого поколения. Если при этом первое поколение тоже окажется за порогом, то оно будет тоже собрано.

Answer (score 0):

Если произойдет "переполнение" (таки у поколений есть пороги) для первого поколения, GC вызовет проверку на первом поколении. Выжившие объекты перейдут во второе, не выжившие - умрут, никакой магии.

[Рихтер в CLR via C#](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21236101/) в главе 21 "Автоматическое управление памятью (уборка мусора)" хорошо описал это.

Comment: то есть этот порог может быть ПРЕВЫШЕН и после этого произойдет проверка первого поколения?

Comment: @khirnick, именно превышен. Как уже выше правильно заметили, порог не фиксирован. Опять же могу посоветовать книгу Рихтера. Там хорошо пошагово расписано как работает GC на разных этапах жизни объектов.

Comment: спасибо! Да, вот только дочитал нужную информацию из 21-ой главы Рихтера